# How do I set authentication_classes on custom route?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a particular custom route on my viewset, which is basically an action on the detail object with an extra parameter in the url (e.g., r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/sub_items/$'). I want to specify a different authentication_class for this route than the rest of the viewset. Where can I specify that? I see there are @list_route and @detail_route dectorators that can be used to specify that, but what about for custom routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Route should set:

`initkwargs={'authentication_classes': (authentication.MyCustomAuthenticationForThisRoute,)}`